# Camera crashes if powerbutton pressed before picturecallback returns

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Following problem: if I press the power button after pressing a take picture button just before the getPictureCallback() methode is called the app crashes.

The camera is loaded in a thread like this:

```
private class CameraHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
    Handler mHandler = null;

    CameraHandlerThread() {
        super("CameraHandlerThread");
        start();
        mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
    }

    synchronized void notifyCameraOpened() {
        notify();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setCameraParameter();
            }
        });
    }

    void openCamera() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                openAndroidCamera();
                notifyCameraOpened();
            }
        });
        try {
            wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LogManager.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            CoreToastDialog.showErrorMessage(getString(R.string.FailedToLoadCamera));
        }
    }
}
```

I interrupt the thread in onPause. Any ideas how to fix this? The bug only occures in a very rare time shift - so only every 30 tries it works maybe once.

If it is PictureCallback, is there any way to fix this?

Error Message:

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410a32a0)
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{DeviceListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: enclose the code in try() catch(Exception e) block for qucik fix.

Comment: please post the crash stack